# Threads not running in parallel after waiting for condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, condition-variable

Please see below the example for `condition_variable` taken from cppreference. In this example, a bunch of threads are waiting for the variable `i` to become `i == 1`. I took the example and just added a `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` instruction inside the workers to check if they were actually running in parallel. To my surprise they don't, so there must be something I am not understanding. Shouldn't all the threads start at the same time once they are notified?

If I remove all the instructions related to `condition_variable`, then the threads do run in parallel as expected, so I believe that my compiler (LLVM with C++11 libraries) is compiling correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m; 
int i = 0;

void waits()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
  std::cerr << "Waiting... \n";
  cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});
  std::cerr << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  std::cerr << "...finished running.\n";
}

void signals()
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cerr << "Notifying...\n";
  }
  cv.notify_all();

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    i = 1;
    std::cerr << "Notifying again...\n";
  }
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t1(waits), t2(waits), t3(waits), t4(signals);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it looks like they are running in parallel, however only one of them will be able to lock `cv_m` mutex after notification and the rest will just wait further.

Comment: seems correct to me. one cannot tell from printing alone what thread runs and where. `std::cerr` is synchronized.

Comment: Thanks VTT. Are you saying that after `cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;})` the lock on `cv_m` is acquired until the end of the scope?

Comment: Yes, add a block from the beginning of the function to before the sleep_for to check this.

Comment: Yes, conditional variable ensures that the protecting mutex is locked before `wait` returns. And it will be automatically unlocked at scope exit, allowing another one thread to acquire the lock and so on.

Comment: Great. Thanks guys! So, if I wanted to have all the workers continue in parallel, do you suggest I do as @stefaanv suggests and wrap the waiting block into a block, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This depends on what you are trying to achieve. In this example threads will exit wait one-by one, however once they are done with mutex lock that protects flag variable they would continue to run in parallel (if they had something else to do).

Comment: Well, ideally they would exit wait all at the same time. One way to do that would be to create as many condition variables/mutex/flag variables as the number of threads. Is that the only way?

Comment: The brutal way to achieve this would be to use something like `volatile bool` as a flag and just loop in child threads `while(!flag);` without any additional sync. Solution with multiple mutexes / condition variables would be even worse than with a single one.

Comment: @VTT volatile bool accessed without a mutex would introduce undefined bevahior due to data race